# Auto-populate Month, Year and Quarter formula fields based on the CloseDate field

Tags: formula, date

There is a object Name "Opportunity" in which there is 4 fields mention below
Closed Date, Month, Year, Quarter.
Now As i fill the date manually , Once i click on "Save" the remaining field i.e 'Month',  'Year' and 'Quarter' should automatically populate
For Eg: Closed Date: 23/02/2013 (Manually filled)
then After Save :  Month=Feb, Year: 2013, and Quarter: 1st. (should automatically filled)

Can anyone help me with this workflow rule or formula and how to do this??

Answer (score 3):

You can create formula fields as follows

Month

```
MONTH(CloseDate)
```

Year

```
YEAR(CloseDate)
```

Quarter

```
FLOOR((MONTH(CloseDate)-1)/3) + 1
```